# JavaScript getComputedStyle not working for color name?

Tags: javascript, css, windows, dom, colors

I'm only asking what I'm doing wrong because I **have** done this before, I just can't remember how and I must've lost the old code.

Firefox has an undocumented color value called `-moz-win-accentcolor` that can be used to get the Windows 10 Accent color.

It works fine if I use that color name directly in a stylesheet (in my extension, to match the theme of the system) but I need to darken or lighten the color a little and I can't do that without getting the color data itself.

This is what I've got, I'm using `window.getComputedStyle` and `getPropertyValue` to get the color data. I don't care if it's hex or RGBA, hell, I don't care if it's binary. I just need to be able to git the color to manipulate color data.

```
function getComputedAccent() {
    let fakeEl = document.createElement("div");

    fakeEl.style = "background: -moz-win-accentcolor";

    return window.getComputedStyle(fakeEl).getPropertyValue("background");
}
```

But this just returns an empty string. Any idea what I've forgotten?

*(Yes, I know this is a hack and I don't care.)*

Comment: "_Any idea what I've forgotten?_" `background` is only a shortcut name for multiple properties, like `background-color`, `background-image`, `background-position`, etc. which are separately stored in CSSDOM object, i.e. `background` property itself doesn't exist.

Comment: @Teemu See answer below. Posted 30 minutes before you.

Comment: There's no answer to the question "_what I've forgotten_" , though. And it is partially wrong too, "_background property isn't_ ..." because it doesn't exist, not that it would contain more content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I was being dumb. The code does work, with a minor change.

```
function getComputedAccent() {
    let fakeEl = document.createElement("div");

    fakeEl.style = "background-color: -moz-win-accentcolor";

    return window.getComputedStyle(fakeEl).getPropertyValue("background-color");
}

getComputedAccent()
"rgb(55, 60, 72)"
```

It was responding with an empty string because the `background` property isn't always just a color. It can be an image. Change it to `background-color` and you're fine.

---

Edited to add more useful code.

```
function getComputedAccent() {
    let fakeEl = document.createElement("div");

    fakeEl.setAttribute("style", "background-color: -moz-win-accentcolor");

    let color = window.getComputedStyle(fakeEl).getPropertyValue("background-color");
    color = color.match(/rgb\((\d+)\s*,\s*(\d+)\s*,\s*(\d+)\s*\)/);
    color.shift();
    color = color.map((value) => parseInt(value, 10));

    return color;
}
```